# python: splitting a long string at distinct places in one run

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, split

I am entirely new to programming and just yesterday started learning python for scientific purposes.

Now, I would like to split a single very long string (174 chars) into several smaller as follows:

```
string = 'AA111-99XYZ '
split = ('AA', 11, 1, -99, 'XYZ')
```

Right now, the only thing I can think of is to use the slice syntax x-times, but maybe there is a more elegant way? Is there a way to use a list of integers to indicate the positions of where to split, e.g.

```
split_at = (2, 4, 5, 8, 11)
split = function(split_at, string)
```

I hope my question is not too silly - I couldn't find a similar example, but maybe I just don't know what I'm looking for?

Thanks,

Jan

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
>>> string = 'AA111-99XYZ '

>>> split_at = [2, 4, 5, 8, 11]

>>> [string[i:j] for i, j in zip([0]+split_at, split_at+[None])]

['AA', '11', '1', '-99', 'XYZ', ' ']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def split_string(string, points):
    for left, right in zip(points, points[1:]):
        yield string[left:right]
```

Comment: example usage: [`print(list(split_string('AA111-99XYZ ', [0, 2, 4, 5, 8, 11])))` -> `['AA', '11', '1', '-99', 'XYZ']`](http://ideone.com/u2pz1K)

Answer (score 0):

to avoid redundancy, you could take ATOzTOA's nice solution and put it in a lamba-function:

```
st = 'AA111-99XYZ '
sa = [2, 4, 5, 8, 11]

res = lambda string,split_at:[string[i:j] for i, j in zip([0]+split_at, split_at+[None])]


print(res(st,sa))
```

Answer (score 0):

Being relatively new to Python myself, I took the approach of a complete beginner here just to help guide someone who isn't yet familiar with the power of Python.

```
string = 'AA111-99XYZ '
split_at = [2, 4, 5, 8, 11]

for i in range(len(split_at)):
    if i == 0:
        print string[:split_at[i]]
    if i < len(split_at)-1:
        print string[split_at[i]:split_at[i+1]]
    if i == len(split_at)-1:
        print string[split_at[i]:]
```